# How do I enable access control on an already up and running MongoDb container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, access-control

Im trying to enable access control on our MongoDb containers without recreating them. They had set the prod Db's without AC enabled and now they're presenting the product to the customers. So me killing the containers and recreating them is not a viable solution right now and I want to know if there is a way to enable AC on them.

What I tried;

Upon my researches both on internet and mongodb university, I found that people enable it by changing the `/etc/mongod.conf` file and restarting it. In my case, when I entered the container via bash, I saw that there is no file named liked that but `mongod.conf.orig`. And I copied that file outside the container, modified it by adding `security: authorization: enabled` and then copied inside. Then I restarted the container but it didnt work.

I also tried to add `--auth` to both `Args` and `Cmd` in `config.v2.json` file of the container. But it resets them after I restart it.

Is it possible to enable AC without recreating the container and am I missing something? I'd much appreciate any help.